# Error while installing kvm package in ubuntu12.04lts

Tags: kvm

```
# apt-get install kvm kvm-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kvm-source
```

While installing kvm in my ubuntu12.04 lts machine. I got this error.What i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this package just doesn't exist:

```
 apt-cache search kvm-source
 #if it returns nothing it means the package doesn't exit
```

As long as we want to search only Ubuntu official repositories, we can also check on http://packages.ubuntu.com/. Here we see that the package kvm [exists](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kvm), but that kvm-source [doesn't](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kvm-source).

If you want to retrieve the source for this package, you should try

```
apt-get source kvm
```

(see `man apt-get` for more info on the `source` command)

---

Edit to answer comment:

You can check if a package is installed with e.g.:

```
dpkg --status kvm
```

Comment: Yes I tried apt-get source kvm. and it works then i check the package with apt-cache search kvm-source. It does not return anything. how to check the package installed with that command.